# What bible translations into different languages are public domain?

Tags: books

It’s hard to find them, wondering if we could collect them here.

- Amharic
- Tibetan
- Chinese
- Greek
- Inuktitut
- Cheyenne
- Pashto
- Etc.

Comment: a good candidate for a community wiki answer

Comment: or seems to be discussed at length and answered here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16377